# Using .format() to print a variable string and a rounded number

Tags: python, string, format, rounding

I want to print something that looks like this:

Hello ¦ 7.16

This is the code I'm using

```
MyString = 'Hello'
MyFloat = 7.157777777
print "{}  ¦  {0:.2f}".format(MyString, MyFloat)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification
```

If I try:

```
MyString = 'Hello'
MyFloat = 7.157777777
print "{s}  ¦  {0:.2f}".format(MyString, MyFloat)
```

or str instead of s I get the error:

```
KeyError: 's'
```

Any ideas how I can print a variable string with a rounded float? Or is there something like `%s` that I should be using?

Answer (score 25):

You are using a *numbered reference* in the second field; the `0` indicates you want to use the first parameter passed to `str.format()` (e.g. `MyString`), not the `MyFloat` value which is parameter `1`.

Since you cannot use the `.2f` format on a string object, you get your error.

Remove the `0`:

```
print "{}  ¦  {:.2f}".format(MyString, MyFloat)
```

as fields without a name or index number are auto-numbered, or use the correct number:

```
print "{}  ¦  {1:.2f}".format(MyString, MyFloat)
```

If you chose the latter, it's better to be explicit consistently and use `0` for the first placeholder:

```
print "{0}  ¦  {1:.2f}".format(MyString, MyFloat)
```

The other option is to use named references:

```
print "{s}  ¦  {f:.2f}".format(s=MyString, f=MyFloat)
```

Note the keyword arguments to `str.format()` there.